# Dynamically change the top margin of a div based on its height

Tags: jquery

I have a div that is fixed to the side of my web page. I need that div to be centered vertically. Easily accomplished using CSS: (note: the base height of the div is 300px;)

```
#sidePanel { margin: -150px 0 0 0; top: 50%; position: fixed;}
```

The issue I'm having is this sidePanel div holds my site navigation. When the nav opens up to show child elements, it grows in height which messes up the centering. I need some jQuery to re-calculate the height of the sidePanel div and the apply the appropriate negative margin to keep the div centered. Here is the jQuery I was playing with:

```
$("#sidePanel").css("margin-top", $(this).outerHeight());
```

I have not worked on the calculation to set the negaitve margin to half of the height, but this is not giving me the height value I'm looking for. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` doesn't refer to the `#sidePanel` element in this case, you would need to either make it with a function passed into [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) like this:

```
$("#sidePanel").css("margin-top", function() { return $(this).outerHeight() });
```

Or a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) call, like this:

```
$("#sidePanel").each(function() {
  $(this).css("margin-top", $(this).outerHeight());
});
```

Or cache the selector, like this:

```
var sp = $("#sidePanel");
sp.css("margin-top", sp.outerHeight());
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, this makes sense. What's the easiest way to make this a negative number??

Comment: @mmsa - just add a `-` :) e.g. `-$(this).outerHeight()`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the margin to the window's height minus the div's height, all divided by two. That should center it vertically.

Comment: I'm new to jQuery. What's the easiest way to grab the window height?