# Dynamically change the top margin of a div based height of another div

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to use the code learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149701/dynamically-change-the-top-margin-of-a-div-based-on-its-height)

to update the top-margin of a fixed position div like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 
    var sw = $(".snw-button-outer-wrapper");
    var hw = $(".header-wrapper"); 
    sw.css("margin-top", hw.outerHeight());
});
```

but the top margin does not update upon change in the outerheight of the header-wrapper div, only once upon initialization. Obviously, I'm very new to javascript/jQuery; where should I go from here? Any insight at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you describe your usecase and/or build a jsFiddle demo? I'am pretty sure there is a js-less solution for this.

Comment: What do you mean by `change in the outerheight of the header-wrapper div`? What changes it?

Comment: Well, this is how i'm using the script: I have an overlaid menu that has a fixed position behind a topbar. The first item within the menu, the snw-button-outer-wrapper has a margin-top value the same height of the topbar thanks to this script. Once the search button is clicked in the topbar it expands an accordion within the bar, pushing everything else down. I'm basically trying for the  referenced margin-top value to toggle based on the topbar's new height. Here's the link: [link](http://c1358.paas2.tx.modxcloud.com/index.php?id=51)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this code needs to run more than once (initial load) then you'd be better off placing this code to run when you click your search button.

For example, something like:

```
$(function(){
    $('#searchButton').on('click', function(){
        var sw = $(".snw-button-outer-wrapper");
        var hw = $(".header-wrapper"); 
        sw.css("margin-top", hw.outerHeight());       
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

```
$('a.searchBtn').on('click', function () { 
    $('#searchAccordion .accordion-navigation [data-external-trigger]').trigger('click.fndtn.accordion');
    var sw = $(".snw-button-outer-wrapper");
    var hw = $(".header-wrapper"); 
    sw.css("margin-top", hw.outerHeight());       
});
```

Comment: Right. Can I have two different onclick functions for one button? I have this already: `$('a.searchBtn').on('click', function () {
        $('#searchAccordion .accordion-navigation [data-external-trigger]').trigger('click.fndtn.accordion');
    });` Thanks for your help.